# UIScrollView Does not show up the second time around

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am building an App using SpriteKit, thus I am only using one ViewController to add or remove subViews. And I always add a new Instance of a subview.

When I'm trying to add a `UIScrollView`, it shows up perfectly fine the first time I add it.
However, after I remove the `UIScrollView` and added it(a new instance of `UIScrollView`) again. The `UIScrollView` does not show up.

The frame of the `UIScrollView` and the `UIStackView` inside are the same for the first time and the second time.

I do not quite understand why it is not working properly. I am guessing it is related to auto-layout, but again, the frame is the same when it is added the first time and the second time.
And, I am not trying to implement auto-layout here.

Here is the class:

```
class StoreScrollV: UIScrollView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: rectOfEntireScreen)
        self.bounds.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        self.contentSize = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 300)
        self.tag = 100
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        self.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.tag = 111
        stackView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 300)
        stackView.frame = stackView.toCenter() 
        //custome function that move the view to the center of its parent with the same size.

        stackView.axis = .horizontal

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let imageV1 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ballCat"))
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageV1)
        
        let imageV2 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ballChicken"))
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageV2)
     
        stackView.spacing = 10;
        stackView.distribution = .equalCentering
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func willMove(toWindow newWindow: UIWindow?) {
        if newWindow != nil {
//            joinAnimationFromTop(view: self)
        } else {
//            leaveAnimationResetToTop(view: self)
        }
    } 
}
```

Here is how I add it:
(the `UIScrollView` is inside another `UIView` that gets added)

```
let storePage = StoreView() //another customized UIView frame is the entire screen at 0,0.
let scrV = StoreScrollV()

storePage.addSubview(scrV)
scrV.frame = scrV.toCenter()
//custome function that move the view to the center of its parent with the same size.

VC.addSubview(viewWithScrollV)
```

[hierarchy debugging the second time ScrollView is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUZNd.png)

[hierarchy debugging the second time ScrollView is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2vPR.png)

Comment: Please provide screenshots of the before and after state of xcode view hierarchy debugging. You can access it in XCode while the app running here: https://i0.wp.com/chelseatroy.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Screen-Shot-2020-04-03-at-1.05.31-PM.png?w=1446&ssl=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

change to

```
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

Problem fixed.

The frame for the scrollView is actually (0,0,0,0). I did not realize this because when I was debugging, I printed out the frame of the scrollView at the end of the init function.

Thus the frame was correct. When I used view hierarchy debugging suggested by Kamil, I realized that the frame has always been wrong.

However, I still do not understand why would it even show up the first time around if the frame is (0,0,0,0).